Holomorphic function when $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}= 0$ only at a point.
So when dealing with holomorphic functions one finds out that
$$f \text{ holomorphic}\implies \text{Cauchy-Riemann}$$
And also the following
$$f \text{ holomorphic}\iff \text{Cauchy-Riemann and } u_x, u_y, v_x,v_y \text{ continuous}$$
Where $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ st $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. One may get to write Cauchy-Riemann equations as it follows:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=0$$
Which means that at least locally $f$ does not depend on $\bar{z}$. My question is: is this true that this works locally? That is, if you find a point $z$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=0$, that may be isolated or not, does this imply that the function may be holomorphic at that point? Or it does in fact imply that the function is not a function of $\bar{z}$ everywhere?
I'm guessing that if that point $z$ is isolated the function can't be holomorphic, since holomorphism needs the function to be not only differentiable at that point but also on a neighbourhood that contains it. But if you find a region where this equation holds, I can't think of any reason for which the function should not be holomorphic there, but I have the feeling that that's not true, so that the only way a function is holomorphic if it does not depend on $\bar{z}$ anywhere.
EDIT: In other words, may there exist a function $f(z, \bar{z})$ that is holomorphic where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=0$, or holomorphic functions are only of the form $f(z)$?

holomorphic

$\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline z}$ is not a "partial derivative with respect to $\overline z$". The Wirtinger derivatives only look like partial derivatives, but $z$ and $\overline z$ are not independent variables, and so you have to be careful when dealing with them

Can you clarify what you mean by "does not depend on $\overline z$"? Obviously if you change $z$ then you also change $\overline z$

Also note that one does not need continuity of the partial derivatives:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looman%E2%80%93Menchoff_theorem

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} \bar{z}^2 = 2\bar{z}$ which is only $0$ when $z = 0$.  The function $f(z) = \bar{z}^2$ is not holomorphic.
The language here is, to my knowledge, not completely standardized.  I might say that $f$ is complex differentiable at such a point, but not holomorphic there (which would require it to be complex differentiable in a neighborhood of the point).
What you can say is that if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}\big|_{z_0} = 0$, then $f(z_0 + h) = f(z_0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\big|_{z_0} h + \mathcal{o}(h)$.
